# PHP contact form not working, getting "Relaying denied" error

Tags: php, html, email, server, localhost

I'm very new to php and made a contact form by following a video but It doesn't seem to work. I was getting a STARTTLS error but then I added

ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");

I don't know why it is gmail and why that port when the original smtp and port are the ones from my ISP and not of gmail, but now that I've added this I get a separate error?

The Error:

Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 5.7.1 relaying denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\ContactForm\form_process.php on line 83

I am running this on a Localhost XAMPP Apache server to test it before signing up for a hosting service. I have included my index.php (mostly html), my form_process.php(the actual error catching and sending of mail is here).

in my php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = mail.mymts.net ;smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=587 ;465

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = ExampleEmail@gmail.com
```

index.php (I'm not sure whether I need like the doctype and header stuff but I added a body because I needed to apply css to the whole body, then a header to organize links and the rest just cuz I thought maybe it's okay):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<?php include ('form_process.php');?>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/email.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>    
        <div id="navbar" class="li flex-container nav hidden-xs">
            <a class="nav-link flex-item " href="index.html#bottom">PHOTOGRAPHER</a>
            <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="Portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
            <a class="hplogo-a flex-item hidden-xs hidden-sm" href=""><img id="logo" src="Images/WHITELOGO.png" alt=""></a>
            <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="Investment.html">INVESTMENT + FAQ</a>
            <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="#">BLOG</a>
        </div>
        <div id="myNav" class="overlay hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <a href="index.html#bottom">PHOTOGRAPHER</a>
                <a href="Portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
                <a href="javascript:window.location.reload();">INVESTMENT + FAQ</a>
                <a href="#">BLOG</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span id="toggle" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()" class="hidden-sm hidden-lg hidden-md popup">&#9776; </span>
        <div class="container top email">

            <p class="eramble eramble1 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10 "> Finding a photographer is a delicate process and you really need to trust your instinct. You put your trust and faith in us to capture your most valuable memories and to tell your story through our camera.  You're here because you feel that my work can represent and accentuate the love between you and your fiancé.</p>
            <p class="eramble eramble2  col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">If this is the case, I would love to hear more about you and about your wedding day.  So, lets start here! </p>
            <div class="email_form">  
                <form id="contact" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group row">

                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <label for="fname">Name*</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Your first name" type="text" tabindex="1" size="30" name="fname" value="<?= $fname ?>" autofocus>
                            <label for="fname" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">First Name</label> 
                            <span class="error"><?= $fname_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                            <label class="visuallyhidden" for="lname">lNAME</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Your last name" type="text" name="lname" value="<?= $lname ?>" tabindex="4" >
                            <label for="lname" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">Last Name</label>
                            <span class="error"><?= $lname_error?> </span> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <label for="email">Email Address*</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" tabindex="2" >
                            <span class="error"><?= $email_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <label for="phone1">Phone*</label>
                            <input class="form-control" size="4" maxlength="3" id="phone1" placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="text" name="phone1" value="<?= $phone1 ?>" tabindex="3" >
                            <label for="phone1" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">(###)</label>
                            <span class="error"><?= $phone1_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <label class="visuallyhidden" for="phone2">Phone*</label>
                            <input class="form-control" size="4" maxlength="3" id="phone2" placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="text" name="phone2" value="<?= $phone2 ?>" tabindex="3" >
                            <label for="phone2" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">###</label>
                            <span class="error"><?= $phone2_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <label class="visuallyhidden" for="phone3">Phone*</label>
                            <input class="form-control" size="5" maxlength="4" id="phone3" placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="text" name="phone3" value="<?= $phone3 ?>" tabindex="3" >
                            <label for="phone3" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; ">####</label>
                            <span class="error"><?= $phone3_error?> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <label for="message">Message*</label>
                            <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." class="message1 form-control" rows="5" id="message" name="message" tabindex="5" ><?php if(isset($_POST['message'])){ 
                    echo htmlentities ($_POST['message']); }?></textarea>
                            <span class="error"><?= $message_error?></span> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <button class="btn-default btn rbutton col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1" name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="success"><?= $success;?></div>
                </form>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container bottom faq">
            <h1>FAQ</h1>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>

            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>
            <h3 class="question col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h3>
            <p class="answer Lastanswer col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint voluptatibus libero unde ipsam, rem quod nesciunt vel amet totam quia, enim, doloribus esse iure, ad. Nesciunt suscipit molestias voluptates explicabo iure error, sapiente qui quam, laboriosam praesentium expedita doloribus magnam. Non aliquam, voluptatum earum odio cumque sapiente aut, necessitatibus</p>





        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <footer class="foot">
                <h6> AVAILABLE WORLDWIDE</h6>      <h6> 2049671111</h6>
                <a href="#">MRPOOPYBUTTHOLE@GMAIL.COM</a>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <script>

            function openNav() {
                document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
            }

            function closeNav() {
                document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
            }
        </script>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

form_process.php:

```
<?php 
// define variables and set to empty values
$fname_error = $lname_error = $email_error = $phone1_error = $phone2_error = $phone3_error = $message_error="";
$fname = $lname = $email = $phone1 = $phone2 = $phone3 = $message = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
    $fname_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $fname_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
    $lname_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $lname_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["phone1"])) {
    $phone1_error = "required";
  } else {
    $phone1 = test_input($_POST["phone1"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed

  }
  if (empty($_POST["phone2"])) {
    $phone2_error = "required";
  } else {
    $phone2 = test_input($_POST["phone2"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed

  }
  if (empty($_POST["phone3"])) {
    $phone3_error = "required";
  } else {
    $phone3 = test_input($_POST["phone3"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
  }    
  if (empty($_POST["url"])) {
    $url_error = "";
  } else {
    $url = test_input($_POST["url"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$url)) {
      $url_error = "Invalid URL"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message_error = "Message is required";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

  if ($fname_error == '' and $lname_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone1_error == '' and $phone2_error == '' and $phone3_error == '' and $url_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }

      $to = 'thetalhasuboor@gmail.com';
      $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
      if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body)){
          $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
          $fname = $lname = $email = $phone1 = $phone2 = $phone3 = $message = $url = '';
      }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: if you want to use gmail to send, you need to use a better mailing library such as phpMailer

Comment: When you say use gmail to send, do you mean gmail's server? Because tbh i dont understand why i need to put my email in send_from in php.ini because shoulsnt the email be sent from whatever email is in the contact form? I assume im interpetting that wrong

Comment: you have to send using a mail server, on local host you dont have one. so you need to use someone else's mail server --most people use gmail. If you had this on a host -`mail()` would probably work by it self

Comment: What about when I actually launch the site? What do I do then, will I need to change my code structure or just the mail server to my hosting service's?

Comment: So do I need to remake my entire php, and build it from the ground up with phpMailer? or can I incorporate it somehow? Sorry, I'm quite new

Comment: download https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer include, look at the examples, you will only have to change\add a a handful of lines

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll take a look at that, hopefully that'll get rid of my error. Also, is there anything that I would need to change in order to launch this on a public server instead of my localhost, besides the ports, n mail servers?

Comment: @nogad I've tried setting this up with phpMailer but I'm having trouble. You said that my code would likely work if I was using a hosting service right?